# How to run several times the same program with different inputs via Python script?

Tags: python, lines

I need to run a simple C program several time, each one with different input string (let's say AAAAA... increasing size, until I get "TRUE" as output).
e.g.

```
./program A # output FALSE
./program AA # output FALSE
./program AAA # output FALSE
./program AAAA # output FALSE
./program AAAAA # output FALSE
./program AAAAAA # output FALSE
./program AAAAAAA  # output TRUE
```

in C I would simply use a **while** loop.
I know in python there is the **while** loop as well.

So the python program would be:

```
strlen = 0
while TRUE
 strlen++
 <run ./**C program** "A"*strlen > 
 if (<program_output> = TRUE)
   break
```

Given that I can make the .py script executable by writing

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

and

```
 chmod +x file.py
```

What should I do to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...that's not a Python program

Comment: I know, the syntax is not  the right one. it's just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)):

```
import subprocess

args = ""
while True:
     args += "A"
     result = subprocess.call(["./program", "{args}".format(args=args)])
     if result == 'TRUE':
         break
```

The `subprocess` module is preferred to the `os.popen` command, since it has been "deprecated since version 2.6." See the [os documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen).

Comment: program is not a .py script, but a C program

Comment: the code works. why do you use "args"? However, the program (./program) after every execution requires a user interrupt (ctrl+C) to stop. And obviously if I do it, the program ./program exists, as well as the .py program. is there any one to make ./program exit, but the .py continue?

Comment: I was using 'args' to refer to the command-line arguments you would be passing in, had you simply ran your c file from command line. You could call that variable whatever you want. And you might be able to do a result.kill() with the revised subprocess.Popen(...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import subprocess
strlen = 0
while True:
    strlen += 1
    if subprocess.check_output(['./program', 'A'*strlen]) == 'TRUE':
        break
```

Comment: I tried the code. It seems to work.. but after 1 loop only it gets stuck. I tried to place print(strlen) after strlen +=1 and indeed it prints 1 only and nothing more (nor the program exits)

Comment: actually it doesn't. he program (./program) after every execution requires a user interrupt (ctrl+C) to stop. And obviously if I do it, the program ./program exists, as well as the .py program. is there any one to make ./program exit, but the .py continue?

Comment: You can set a `timeout` argument to `check_output` (see the doc linked above). A cleaner way would be to use `subprocess.Popen` directly (`check_output` is a wrapper), read the four first characters from the process' stdout, and then kill it.

Answer (score 1):

**file.py**

```
import os

count=10
input="A"
for i in range(0, count):
    input_args=input_args+input_args
    os.popen("./program "+input_args)
```

running **file.py** would execute **./program** 10 times with increasing `A` input

Comment: program is not a .py script, but a C program

Comment: @dragonmnl made changes to run `program` as executable

Answer (score 1):

Use `commands`. Here is the documentation `http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html`

1. `commands.getstatusoutput` returns a stdout output from your C program. So, if your program prints something, use that. (In fact, it returns a tuple (0, out) for stdout).
2. `commands.getstatus` returns boolean status from program which you can use as well.

So, assuming you are using stdout to capture the `./program` output, the entire modified program looks like

```
import commands

while TRUE:
  strlen += 1
  output = commands.getstatusoutput("./program " + "A"*strlen)
  outstatus = output[1]
  if output == "true":
     break
```

I would experiment with `getstatus` to see if I can read values returned by `program`.

**Edit:** Didn't notice that `commands` is deprecated since 2.6 Please use `subprocess` as shown in other response.

Comment: **Don't** use `commands`. Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead. The big fat warning at the top of the documentation for `commands` tells you: *Deprecated since version 2.6*.

Comment: Oops.. Didn't notice the deprecated part. I used it sometime back, not recently